# AS3: Excluding duplicate classes from child SWF to reduce file size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, adobe-animate

I'm using Adobe Animate to make a parent SWF that loads other child SWFs. When I'm compiling the child Flashes, is there a way to exclude certain duplicate classes which will already exist in the parent Flash in order to decrease the file size? I assume the child Flashes would no longer be able to execute on their own, but they're not supposed to, they're supposed to only be played through the parent. Is this possible in Adobe Animate, or do I need something like Flash Builder to do that?

Comment: You can have SWC library with these classes linked as "external" or "runtime shared", something like that, opposite from "include", and compile your SWF. Doable from Flash/Animate IDE. It, of course, will render your SWF unable to run on its own.